# Display properties file location in client code

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a bean declared in my applicationContext file like this:

```
<util:properties id="myProperties" scope="prototype" location="file:${catalina.home}/webapps/myProperties.properties"/>
```

in my client code I use this bean to retrieve the properties file like this:

```
Properties props = context.getBean("myProperties", Properties.class);
```

This is in a try catch block in case the properties file is not in the correct location initially.

When the code fails an error is displayed on the screen that says 'Properties file can not be found'.

My question is can I also display the path where spring is looking for the properties file in the client code?  So my new error message would say: Properties file can not be found in: ' somePath.

Thanks

Comment: Well you have simply to reproduce the path you have declared. So is it the problem to resolve the "catalina.home" environment variable?

Comment: Well I'd imagine the path will be slightly different between windows and linux servers.  I want it displayed on the screen so I need to have a getPath call somewhere after the context.getBean(...) call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like [user625146](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625146/user625146) said, you could just retrieve the system property `catalina.home` e.g. (some pseudo code)

```
String prop = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
throw new Error ("msg" + prop + "/webapps/myProperties.properties");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) to set the location and inject it into your controller or another bean in an additional field, too. Convert the file name there to the system dependent file name with help of the File class [`getCanonicalFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile%28%29) method.